# Taking the difference of two arrays and making a new array

Tags: javascript

I need this function to compare two arrays and return a new array that only contains elements that aren't common to both arrays. I wrote the following code:

```
function diff(arr1, arr2) {

  var newArray = [];

  for (var i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){
    for (var j=0;j<arr2.length;j++){
      if (arr1[i]===arr2[j]){

        arr1.splice(i,1);
        arr2.splice(j,1);
      }
    }
  }
  newArray = arr1.concat(arr2);
  return newArray;
}

diff([1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

but it returns [2,2,4] instead of just [4]

Also, I tried writing it using the filter method:

```
function diff(arr1, arr2) {

  var newArray = [];

  function compare(x){
    for (var i = 0;i<arr2.length;i++){
      return x != arr2[i];
    }
  }
  newArray = arr1.filter(compare);
  return newArray; 
}

diff([1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

and that doesn't work for every instance either.
I need to be able to compare arrays with numbers and strings as well.
It has to be in javascript, no jquery for this.

Comment: *"It has to be in javascript, no jquery for this."* jQuery *is* JavaScript. However, jQuery's domain is DOM manipulation, not processing collections.

Comment: Your implementations are weird. How would you do that manually if you were provided 2 lists of numbers on paper and you needed to produce the third diff one?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/dugutitixi/2/edit

Comment: numbers and strings? meaning you want to preserve the type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try:

```
function diff(arr1, arr2) {

    var tmp = [];
    var newArray = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
            if (arr1[i] === arr2[j]) {
                arr1[i] = arr2[j] = null;
            }
        }
    }
    tmp = arr1.concat(arr2);
    for (var i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
        if (tmp[i] !==null) {
            newArray.push(tmp[i]);
        }
    }
    return newArray;
}

console.log(diff([0,1,2], [1,2]));//output: [0]
```

Comment: Doesn't work for `diff([0,1,2], [1,2])`, but the general idea isn't too bad.

Comment: Works for numbers and stings at least :) you might want to add a bit more explanation than just "try this".

Comment: Thanks several of the answers worked... I've been stuck on this forever

Comment: O(N*M) is easy, come on :)

Answer (score 1):

When you `splice` the array all the elements move down in their position, this makes your loop jump a step. For example when it removes the `1`'s in the `0th` position the `2`'s move to the new `0th` part you already checked that it skips over next. A simple way to fix that is when you splice make sure you back step, you can decrement both `i` and `j`:

```
  if (arr1[i]===arr2[j]) {
    arr1.splice(i,1);
    arr2.splice(j,1);
    i--; 
    j--;  
  }
```

Comment: @FelixKling I see what you mean, would you mind providing an example where this would fail?

Comment: Actually, maybe it does not "fail" depending on the desired outcome. My remark was for arrays with duplicate elements. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/2b9hLrhj/. Here, `2` is contained in the final array, even though it appears in both of them. It's correct if you consider each element individually regardless its value. If one has more of "set perspective" on the arrays, then `2` should probably not be included in the final array. But then, what if one array contains `4` twice? Should `4` appear twice in the result array or once? I'm probably overthinking this and which way to go depends on the

Comment: @FelixKling Yes I was thinking considering each element regardless of the value. I was, for example, thinking `[1,1]-[1] -> [1]`. But that was simply based on that what it appears the OP wanted to do.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense to me now. Sorry for overcomplicating things. Since you are modifying i, it's fine. If I hadn't moved that call in my solution, that would have really created wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

`.splice` mutates the array, so it messes with your loop. A simple fix for your code would be to iterate in reverse order:

```
for (var i=arr1.length; i--;){
  for (var j=arr2.length; j--){

  }
}
```

However that still has the problem that you are splicing `arr1` too often. `arr1` should only be spliced once per iteration:

```
for (var i=arr1.length; i--;){
  var same = false;
  for (var j=arr2.length; j--;){
    if (arr1[i] === arr2[j]) {
      same = true;
      arr2.splice(j, 1);
      break;
    }
  }
  if (same) {
    arr1.splice(i, 1);
  }
}
```

```js
function diff(arr1, arr2) {
  for (var i = arr1.length; i--;) {
    var same = false;
    for (var j = arr2.length; j--;) {
      if (arr1[i] === arr2[j]) {
        same = true;
        arr2.splice(j, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
    if (same) {
      arr1.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  return arr1.concat(arr2);
}

console.log(diff([1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

Comment: `diff([1,1], [2])` seems to correctly produce `[1,1,2]`.

Comment: @DondiMichaelStroma that looks right, based on the criteria of the question

Answer (score 0):

Sort the two arrays, remove duplicates from them, join the two arrays, sort the obtained array, and remove duplicates from the obtained array.

```
function getArraysDifference(a1, a2) {

    sortAndRemoveDuplicates(a1);
    sortAndRemoveDuplicates(a2);
    var outputArray = a1.concat(a2)
    sortAndRemoveDuplicates(outputArray);
    return outputArray; 

}

function sortAndRemoveDuplicates(inputArray) {

    inputArray.sort();
    var lastValue = inputArray[0];
    var i = 0;
    var currentValue;

    for (i = 1; i < inputArray.length; i++) {

        currentValue = inputArray[i];

        if (currentValue === lastValue) {
            inputArray.splice(i, 1);
            i--;
        } else {
            lastValue = currentValue;
        }

    }

}
```

<del>You'll have a worst case time complexity of O((N+M)log(N+M))</del>. The solution you are trying works but is time complexity O(N*M).

#### EDIT

It turned out that since webkit (I did not investigate on other browsers) uses selection sort for sorting, this solution leads to a time complexity O(N M).
In Java this approach should be faster though, as the engine can reach even O(N) for sorting reasonably short arrays, otherwise falling back on O(N log(N)) complexity for sorting.

Comment: That only works for arrays with unique elements though.

Comment: Just keep the reference to the last different found element. It works easily even with duplicate elements.

Comment: I'm not convinced about that. Say I have `[1,2,2,3]` and `[1,4]`, I would get `[1,1,2,2,3,4]` and according to your description, I would get `[3,4]` instead of `[2,2,3,4]`. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Felix you are right. It's enough sorting both the arrays first, remove duplicates, join them, sort the new one and proceed. I've edited the answer. Still faster than the accepted answer is'n it? :)

Answer (score 0):

Set a temporary object. Iterate over both arrays. For each element in each array, if that element is NOT a key within our temporary object, set a key in that object equal to that element with a value of `true`. If an element has already been visited, delete it.

At the end, return Object.keys(obj) to get an array of the keys.

```
function differenceOfTwoArrays(arr1, arr2) {
  var obj = {};

  arr1.forEach(function(elem) {
    if (!obj[elem]) {
      obj[elem] = true;
    } else if (obj[elem]) {
      delete (obj[elem]);
    }
  });

  arr2.forEach(function(elem) {
    if(!obj[elem]) {
      obj[elem] = true;
    } else if (obj[elem]) {
      delete (obj[elem]);
    }
  });

  return Object.keys(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With less code than other answers:

```
function diff(arr1, arr2) {
  var newArray = [];
  for (var i=0;i<arr1.length;i++) {
    if (arr2.indexOf(arr1[i]) == -1) newArray.push(arr1[i]);
  }
  for (var i=0;i<arr2.length;i++){
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) newArray.push(arr2[i]);
  }
  return newArray;
}
```

**Edit**:
Comparison of some of the answers here:
https://jsfiddle.net/c42wvvr5/2/

Seems this answer is fastest by far on Chrome, and slightly slower than Yang's on Firefox.

Converting array values to object keys can make it faster:

```
function diff_dms2(arr1, arr2) {
  var newArray = [];
  var ob1 = { };
  var ob2 = { };
  for (var i=0; i<arr1.length; i++) ob1[arr1[i]] = true;
  for (var i=0; i<arr2.length; i++) ob2[arr2[i]] = true;
  for (var i=0;i<arr1.length;i++) {
    if (!ob2[arr1[i]]) newArray.push(arr1[i]);
  }
  for (var i=0;i<arr2.length;i++){
    if (!ob1[arr2[i]]) newArray.push(arr2[i]);
  } 
  return newArray;
}
```

I would choose the one with the simpler code though unless you have really huge arrays.

Comment: How exactly is that faster?

Comment: That looks like yours is the slowest, and mine is  fastest but wrong (contains `null` values :-/).

Comment: @FelixKling speed seems to depend highly upon the implementation, Chrome and Firefox show opposite results. I should have expected that ;)

Comment: Ah yeah, big difference between Chrome and Firefox. *edit:* Me too :D

Comment: And please don't get me wrong, my comment was not doubting that your code might be more performant (although you are still doing 2 n*m loops, `indexOf` doesn't come for cheap), but *saying* that it is is easy. I would have preferred some explanation of why it would/could be faster.

Comment: @FelixKling I understand you were looking for an explanation. I didn't have one except overconfidence, I was in a rush to get my answer posted while somebody still cared ;0

Comment: The second example seems to get the intersection, not the difference. Uh, actually, I don't know if there is a name for that: `diff_dms2([1,2,3], [2,3,4]) -> [2, 3, 2, 3]`.

Comment: Oops, the `if` statements were supposed to be negated.

Comment: Just tried mine, and resulted to be much slower than it should! And that's because webkit uses selection sort for sorting array :( That's O(N N)! In Java should be faster as the engine can even reach O(N) for sorting reasonably short arrays, otherwise falling back on O(N*log(N)) complexity for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fun "reference" implementation. Its purpose is not to be particularly fast or efficient, but to be correct and to elucidate the algorithm from the code, which helps ensure correctness. You can write "better" versions and compare them against this one for correctness.
"Automated testing is best testing." :-)

It does exactly what was stated in the question: elements -- not necessarily integers -- common to both arrays are expunged from both arrays. This means duplicate items in one array that aren't found in the other left untouched.

```js
function arrayDiff( array1, array2 ) {
    var r1 = array1.slice();
    var r2 = array2.slice();
    var r1Unique = []; // collector for known "unique" values
    while( !r1.every( function( r1Obj ) {
        var uniqueR1Obj = r2.every( function( r2Obj ) {
            if( r1Obj !== r2Obj ) {
                return true; // unique so far, keep processing
            }
            // collision: remove all references to this object in R2
            var newR2 = [];
            r2.forEach( function( oldR2Obj ) {
                if( oldR2Obj !== r2Obj ) {
                    newR2.push( oldR2Obj );
                }
            } );
            r2 = newR2; // start operating on the new smaller array
            return false; // uniqueness lost, bail
        } );
        if( uniqueR1Obj ) {
            r1Unique.push( r1Obj );
        }
        // remove all references to this object in R1
        var newR1 = [];
        r1.forEach( function( oldR1Obj ) {
            if( oldR1Obj !== r1Obj ) {
                newR1.push( oldR1Obj );
            }
        } );
        r1 = newR1; // start operating on the new smaller array
        return uniqueR1Obj; // keep processing if still unique, or bail
    } ) );
    return r1Unique.concat( r1.concat( r2 ) );
}

function addTestResults( r1, r2 ) {
    var s = 'arrayDiff( [ ' + r1 + ' ], [ ' + r2 + ' ] ) == [ ' + arrayDiff( r1, r2 ) + ' ]<br/>';
    el = document.getElementById( "output" );
    if( el !== null )
        el.innerHTML += s;
}

var testArray1 = [ 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 0 ];
var testArray2 = [ 1, 1, 3, 8, 15 ];
var testArray3 = [ 32, 3, 8, 0, 8, 8, 15 ];
            
addTestResults( testArray1, testArray2 );
addTestResults( testArray2, testArray3 );
addTestResults( testArray1, testArray3 );
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

That bit of HTML is just there to act as an "output device". I'm not an expert on the code snippet stuff.

Here's another way to see it: http://jsfiddle.net/Lp1zveba/

Addendum: I can't comment on other answers yet, but I [like the one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30586220/4963471) from '[rkho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2694800/rkho)'; here's a comparison of it and my submission: http://jsfiddle.net/uuh7afLc/

It shows some discrepancies, which I would chalk up to a different interpretation of the question; I took it quite literally to mean that if an element is common between the two arrays, it ( and all its ilk ) will not appear in the result array. Some other answers use the alternate interpretation that *for each pair* of like objects, one is removed from each of the source arrays, and any unmatched leftovers in either array survive the journey to the result array.

Asker is encouraged to clarify the spec. :-)